# Calling C# static void methods with no parameters that require multiple Console entries

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# and trying to call a static void method with multiple console input like this one here:

```
static void CustomerInfo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Custom First Name: ");
    string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Customer Last Name: ");
    string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Customer Address: ");
    string address = Console.ReadLine();

}
static void PrintCustomerDetails(string first, string last, string
address)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} address is: {2}", first, last, address);
}
```

This should return all required CustomerInfo but I'm getting just the Firt Name as input on the Console. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You dont show where you call `PrintCustomerDetails`. Apart from that, `CustomerInfo` does nothing because the strings are stored in local variables which cannot be accesssed from outside.

Comment: @skoye Variables are scoped inside the method how they can be visible at all outside `CustomerInfo` method?

Answer (score 0):

call your method **PrintCustomerDetails** like this

```
static void CustomerInfo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Custom First Name: ");
    string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Customer Last Name: ");
    string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Customer Address: ");
    string address = Console.ReadLine();

    PrintCustomerDetails(firstName, lastName, address);
}
```